Add a second `groupname_col` in `gt` table without concatenating the column values
I love gt's ability to separate row groups into columns, but I want to have TWO row groups as columns, not one column with two groups concatenated, which is the default. For example:
library(gt)

gtcars %>%
  group_by(mfr, year) %>%
  gt(row_group_as_column = TRUE)

This gives us a gt table that looks like this, with the Make and the year concatenated into one column. Is there a way to have two separate grouping columns, one for the mfr and one for the year?


library(gt)
library(dplyr)

gtcars %>%
  mutate(mfr = factor(mfr, levels = unique(mfr))) %>%  ## keep the original order
  arrange(mfr, year) %>%   
  mutate(year = ifelse(row_number() == 1, as.character(year), ""),
         .by = c(mfr, year)) %>% 
  mutate(mfr = ifelse(row_number() == 1, as.character(mfr), ""),
         .by = mfr) %>% 
  select(mfr, year, everything()) %>% 
  gt()



I had the same question, and based on the answer code I wanted to customize the table, I know my code is not written in an elegant way, but I think can be useful for someone
gtcars %>%
  mutate(mfr = factor(mfr, levels = unique(mfr))) %>%  ## keep the original order
  arrange(mfr, year) %>%   
  mutate(year = ifelse(row_number() == 1, as.character(year), ""),
         .by = c(mfr, year)) %>% 
  mutate(mfr = ifelse(row_number() == 1, as.character(mfr), ""),
         .by = mfr) %>% 
  select(mfr, year, everything()) %>% 
  gt() %>% # from here down is my customization
  tab_style(style = cell_borders(sides = "bottom", color = "white"), # Since the background is white, I leave the bottom edges white on certain rows in columns 1 and 2  
            locations = cells_body(columns= 1,rows = c(2:9,13,14,17,18,20:23,25:27,31:34,38,41:43,46))) %>%
  tab_style(style = cell_borders(sides = "bottom", color = "white"), 
            locations = cells_body(columns= 2,rows = c(3:7,14,17,18,20:23,25,26,32:34,38,41,43,46))) %>%
  tab_style(style = cell_borders(sides = "bottom", color = "gray"),
            locations = cells_body(rows = c(1,10,11,12,15,16,19,24,28,29,30,35,36,37,39,40,44))) %>% # To delimit "mfr". Row number to which I assign a color on the bottom edge
  tab_style(style = cell_borders(sides = "right", color = "gray"), locations = cells_body(columns= 2))


gt table
